# gestureRecognizer: shouldReceiveTouch: not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: method isnt being called. Have i set it up improperly?

```
-(id) init 
{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *touchHold = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchHold:)];
touchHold.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
touchHold.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addGestureRecognizer:touchHold];
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
     return NO;
}
```

Press and hold method is still being called even though i set the bool to no.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems like you haven't set the delegate ?

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Is the part of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. So you should have set the delegate too.

```
touchHold.delegate = self;
```

Edit:
You should tell your view controller to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. Something like

```
@interface YourViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Comment: `Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'HelloWorldLayer *'`

Comment: do you have the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> on your @interface YourViewController <...>

Comment: ah i had `@interface YourViewController { id<UIGestureRecognizer>delegate;}` and was setting `touchHold.delegate = delegate;` Thanks for your help, works now. Was confused there for a second.