# Swift: shouldReceiveTouch didn't get called

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a text field to search, with an autocomplete list (`UITableView`) to show the results. I want to dismiss the keyboard while user clicks outside the textfield, and that works; however it breaks my table interaction(user can clicks one of the results to add a record).

I have tried `shouldReceiveTouch` ([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869541/gesturerecognizer-shouldreceivetouch-not-getting-called), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath)) with `UIGestureRecognizer`, however the function doesn't get called. I have

- Added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to ViewController.swift as follow:

  `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {...}`
- Added `UITapGestureRecognizer` object into storyboard and linked it to my view
- Added `IBAction` function to dismiss the keyboard and linked it to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` object:

  ```
  @IBAction func endEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
      addButton.hidden = true
      autocompleteList.hidden = true
      self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
  ```
- Called `shouldReceiveTouch`:

  ```
  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
      println("in shouldReceiveTouch")
      gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
       if (touch.view == autocompleteList){
          println("touching autocomplete list")
          return false
      }
      else{
          println("touching elsewhere")
          return true
      }
  }
  ```

After running the app I learned that `shouldReceiveTouch` never gets called from the console, so my guess is I didn't set up the delegate correctly; I have been looking here and there for a few hours but still no luck. Other solutions to achieve the same goal are welcome as well. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: have you set the delegate implementer to your ViewController class in story board?

Comment: also please check if the gesture recognizer exist at the top of all other subviews and return false for views which should be excluded from gesture recognizer in shouldReceiveTouch

Comment: @SanjayMohnani you saved my day. I didn't set the delegate in the connection inspector. Now it calls the function! Thanks so much